# Can an integral of a function be multi-valued?

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider $f(z) = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x - z} dx$, where $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus [0, 1]$. The usual calculation gives us $f(z) = \log |\frac{1 - z}{-z}|$, but the $\log$ function on the complex plane is multi-valued unless we specify a branch. But this seems weird, as I have never heard that the integral of a function can be multi-valued.

Comment: If you fix a path you fix an integral. I presume $\int_0^1$ means you are integrating along the line segment from $0$ to $1$. But there are many paths in $\Bbb C$ from $0$ to $1$, and integrating over some of them will give different results.

Comment: @AnginaSeng In a complex setting, what you suggest is not generally true.  In complex-land, if a function is holomorphic on a domain $f$, then $\int_{\gamma_1} f = \int_{\gamma_2} f$ for any two homotopic curves $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$.  The function given here satisfies the requirements of the theorem as long as we don't consider paths which wrap around the pole.

Comment: @Hnur123  Fix a branch of the logarithm *first*, then integrate.  There should be no need for the modulus in your logarithm (since you are working with complex logarithms).  If you are not familiar with it, you might want to read up on the Cauchy integral formula.  This integral you are working with motivates the more general result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(z)$ be given by the integral $f(z)=\int_0^1 \frac1{x-z}\,dx$ where the path of integration is on the line segment $[0,1]$.

If $z\in \mathbb{R}$, with $z>1$ or $z<0$, then

$$f(z)=\log\left|\frac{1-z}{-z}\right|$$

If $z\in \mathbb{R}$, and $z\in [0,1]$, then the integral fails to exist.  For $z\in (0,1)$, the Cauchy Principal Value of the integral does exist.

If $z\in \mathbb{C}$, and $\text{Im}(z)\ne 0$, then we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x-z}\,dx&=\int_0^1 \frac{x-\text{Re}(z)}{x^2+|z|^2-2x\text{Re}(z)}\,dx+\int_0^1 \frac{i\text{Im}(z)}{x^2+|z|^2-2x\text{Re}(z)}\,dx\\\\
&=\log\left(\frac{|1-z|}{|z|}\right)\\\
&+i\text{sgn}(\text{Im}(z))\left(\arctan\left(\frac{1-\text{Re}(z)}{|\text{Im}(z)|}\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{-\text{Re}(z)}{|\text{Im}(z)|}\right)\right)
\end{align}$$

Alternatively, we have in terms of the multi-valued logarithm

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{1}{x-z}\,dx&=\log(1-z)-\log(-z)\\\\
&=\log(|1-z|)+i\arg(1-z)-\log(|-z|)-i\arg(-z)\\\\
&=\log\left(\frac{|1-z|}{|z|}\right)+i\left(\arg(1-z)-\arg(-z)\right)
\end{align}$$

> **NOTE:**While $\arg(z)$ is multivalued, the difference $\arg(1-z)-\arg(-z)$ is not multivalued and does not depend on the choice of branch.  This is because the branch cut cannot pass through the line segment $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see that arg(1-z) - arg(-z) is not multi-valued.

Comment: Regardless of which branch is chosen, the difference $\arg(1-z)-\arg(-z)$ is the same.